# how to stop receiving location update in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

i am making location tracking application.
For that i put two buttons stop and start, on  start button click receiving location update is enable,
on stop button click stop receiving location update.

but stop receiving location update is not working.

```
                            package com.jaygandhi.tracking;


                    import android.Manifest;
                    import android.content.IntentSender;
                    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
                    import android.location.Location;
                    import android.os.Bundle;
                    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
                    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
                    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
                    import android.util.Log;
                    import android.view.View;
                    import android.widget.Button;
                    import android.widget.Toast;

                    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
                    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
                    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
                    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
                    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
                    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
                    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
                    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
                    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
                    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
                    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
                    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

                    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
                            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
                            LocationListener {

                        private Button bStop, bStart;
                        private boolean mRequestLocationUpdates = false;
                        private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

                        public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

                        /*
                         * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
                         * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
                         */
                        private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

                        private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

                        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
                        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


                        Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

                        private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5 * 1000;
                        private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 1 * 1000;
                        private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;


                        @Override
                        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
                            setUpMapIfNeeded();

                            bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
                            bStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstop);


                            if (checkPlayServices()) {
                                buildGoogleApiClient();
                                createLocationRequest();
                            }

                            /*mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                                    .build();

                            // Create the LocationRequest object
                            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                                    .setInterval(5 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                                    .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

                    */

                            bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    //togglePeriodLocationUpdates();
                                    startLocationUpdates();
                                }
                            });

                            bStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    //togglePeriodLocationUpdates();
                                    //stopLocationUpdates();
                                    stopLocationUpdates();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        /*public void st()
                        {
                            mRequestLocationUpdates = true;

                            startLocationUpdates();
                        }

                        public void sp()
                        {

                            mRequestLocationUpdates = false;

                            stopLocationUpdates();
                        }
                    */
                        /*private void togglePeriodLocationUpdates()
                        {
                            if(!mRequestLocationUpdates)
                            {


                                mRequestLocationUpdates = true;

                                startLocationUpdates();
                            }

                            else
                            {


                                mRequestLocationUpdates = false;

                                stopLocationUpdates();
                            }
                        }*/

                        protected void startLocationUpdates() {
                            mRequestLocationUpdates = true;

                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                // TODO: Consider calling
                                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                                return;
                            }
                            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);


                            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(mRequestLocationUpdates));
                            //Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient));


                        }

                        protected void stopLocationUpdates()
                        {

                            mRequestLocationUpdates = false;
                            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

                            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(mRequestLocationUpdates));
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onStart()
                        {
                            super.onStart();
                            if(mGoogleApiClient != null)
                            {
                                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                                //setUpMapIfNeeded();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onResume()
                        {
                            super.onResume();
                            checkPlayServices();


                            //mGoogleApiClient.connect();

                            if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() )
                            {
                                if(mRequestLocationUpdates)
                                {
                                    startLocationUpdates();
                                    setUpMapIfNeeded();
                                }

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onStop()
                        {
                            super.onStop();

                            if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
                            {
                                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onPause() {
                            super.onPause();

                            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
                            {
                                stopLocationUpdates();
                            }
                        }

                        /**
                         * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
                         * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
                         * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
                         * <p/>
                         * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
                         * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
                         * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
                         * <p/>
                         * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
                         * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
                         * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
                         * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
                         * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
                         */
                        private void setUpMapIfNeeded()
                        {
                            // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
                            if (mMap == null)
                            {
                                // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
                                mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                        .getMap();
                                // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
                                if (mMap != null)
                                {
                                    setUpMap();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        /**
                         * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
                         * just add a marker near Africa.
                         * <p/>
                         * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
                         */
                        private void setUpMap()
                        {
                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                // TODO: Consider calling
                                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                                return;
                            }
                            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));

                        }

                        private void handleNewLocation(Location location)
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG, location.toString());


                            double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                            double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

                            Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed " + currentLatitude +" , "
                                    + currentLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            if (mCurrLocationMarker != null)
                            {
                                mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
                            }
                            //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
                            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(latLng)
                                    .title("I am here!");

                            mCurrLocationMarker= mMap.addMarker(options);
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
                        {
                            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                            if (location == null)
                            {
                                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                handleNewLocation(location);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
                        {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)
                        {
                            /*
                             * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
                             * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
                             * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
                             * error.
                             */
                            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                                try {
                                    // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                                    /*
                                     * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                                     * PendingIntent
                                     */
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    // Log the error
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                /*
                                 * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
                                 * user with the error.
                                 */
                                Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
                        {
                            handleNewLocation(location);
                        }

                        private boolean checkPlayServices()
                        {
                            int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
                            if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
                            {
                                if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
                                {
                                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                    finish();
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }


                        protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
                        {
                            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
                        }

                        protected void createLocationRequest()
                        {
                            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
                            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
                            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Listening to location changes is better using a LocationManager and implementing LocationListener, you dont need GoogleClient to listen to the location updates.

To listen to locations update correctly you must do the following

```
//Declare a location manager
 private LocationManager locationManager;

//Request location update either by GPS or NETWORK and for accurate results use //GPS

 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 3, this);

//and the new locations will go to the onLocationChanged(Location location) //method that you already overrided
```

now to stop listening to the location updates just use this

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

Comment: Using the GoogleApiClient/Fused Location Provider is not "the wrong way" and it can get the real location as well just as described [in the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#updates). Of course using the LocationManager is fine as well.